# Godot Mono cannot find .NET framework 4.7

Tags: c#, godot

I cannot get anything to compile in Godot Mono using C#.  It keeps giving me the following error:

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [C:\Users\my_name\Desktop\GODOT\Projects\test\Test.csproj]

I have installed the SDK found [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net472) which did not fix the problem.  Maybe I need to explicitly direct Godot to it, but I can't find any option to do so.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You link the 4.7.2 version of the SDK, not the [4.7 version](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net47) - did you try that one? - I remind you we are talking SDKs. The runtime might be keeping compatibility down to .NET 4.5 and up to its version. However, for SDKs, you usually need the specific one.